# Hangman game runs okay in stepping mode but delays making shapes visible in normal mode

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up this hangman game however, so far it only works in stepping mode.

What happens after pressing play is that if I choose a wrong letter, it does not show "hangman" shape until I make a correct guess.

So, for example, if I make 2 incorrect guesses (so there should be 2 shapes showing before repeating the loop), nothing happens until my 3rd guess is correct, then it shows both shapes at once.

The code works fine in stepping mode, if i go through the code with F8, there are no issues, shapes show up in order. Not really sure what could be the issue here.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim word As Range
Dim rect As Shape

Sub Hangman()


Dim fletter As Variant
Dim myLetter As String
Dim i As Byte

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set word = wks.Range("B1:J1")

i = 1

Do Until wks.Range("b1:j1").Font.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbBlack Or i = 9

myLetter = VBA.InputBox("What is the next letter")

Set word = Range("B1:J1").Find(myLetter)




        If Not word Is Nothing Then

        word.Font.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbBlack
        fletter = word.Address

            Do

            Set word = Range("B1:J1").FindNext(word)
            word.Font.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbBlack

            If word.Address = fletter Then Exit Do


            Loop

        Else


        Set rect = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.shapes("Shape" & i)

        rect.Visible = msoTrue


        i = i + 1

        End If


   Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: you need to put the `wks` in front of the `Range`s and the `shapes`

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for correcting my post first of all. I followed your advice however no luck, the code is still delaying the appearance of the shapes.

Comment: add `wks.Calculate` before your last loop

Comment: Perfect! it works! much appreciated, thank you.